# Запрос с использованием like

Tags: sql, mysql

Люди, подскажите... Забыл ненмого, как правильно запросы писать...

```
SELECT `post_title`,`id` FROM `{$wpdb->prefix}posts` WHERE `post_title` LIKE '%{$searcher}%' or `post_content` LIKE '%{$searcher}%' and `post_status` = 'publish'
```

В данном запросе почему-то не выполняется условие "and". С такой проблемой сталкивался уже, но не помню, как решалась она... Вроде кавычки где-то ставить надо или что-то ещё на подобии...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Спасибо, уже разобрался...

```
SELECT post_title,id FROM {$wpdb->prefix}posts WHERE (post_title LIKE '%{$searcher}%' or post_content LIKE '%{$searcher}%') and post_status = 'publish'
```

Скобочки пропустил :(